# too many redirections have happened while trying to open the login page

Tags: spring, redirect

I use spring and spring security for my application

Here is my spring security xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBRE')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
<!--        <security:form-login login-page="/login.jsp" -->
<!--            default-target-url="/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp" -->
<!--            authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp" username-parameter="username" -->
<!--            password-parameter="password" /> -->
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <security:csrf />
        <security:custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
            ref="authenticationFilter" />
        <security:anonymous enabled="true" />
    </security:http>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider
            ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="authenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
        <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="encoder"
        class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder" />

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="spring.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

    <bean id="passwordChecker" class="spring.security.impl.PasswordCheckerImpl" />

    <bean id="authenticationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/login" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="spring.security.AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl">
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/WEB-INF/pages/index.jsp" />
        <property name="userManagementService" ref="userManagementService" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="authenticationFailureHandler" class="spring.security.AuthenticationFailureHandlerImpl">
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/login.jsp" />
        <property name="userManagementService" ref="userManagementService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userManagementService" class="spring.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl">

    </bean>


</beans>
```

When I try to open my login page I have the following error message on safari : too many redirection occured when trying to open the page. This can happen when you open a page that is redirected towards another page that redirect again towards the original page

on firefox, the message error is : the page is not redirected correctly. Firefox detected that the server redirect the demand for this adress in a way that will not be successfull

I don't see what could be the cause. Thanks in advance for your answers

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by changing the security:http by

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
<security:intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp" access="isAnonymous()" />
<security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous()" />
<security:logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
<!-- enable csrf protection -->
<security:csrf />
<security:custom-filter after="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
    ref="authenticationFilter" />
<security:anonymous enabled="true" />
```